# How can I make a div into the center

Tags: html, css

I want to make a registration form

How can I align this box like right under the head title?

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.registrerBoks {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>registrer</h1>
<div class="registrerBoks">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin:auto`:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.registrerBoks {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>registrer</h1>
<div class="registrerBoks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: auto;` to the registerBoks form.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.registrerBoks {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>registrer</h1>
<div class="registrerBoks">

</div>
```